# Getting the real parts of eigenvalues in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the real parts of the eigenvalues, I coming across this error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'real'

```
def get_eig_real(matrix):
  eig= linalg.eig(M)
  eig=eig.real
  print(eig)
get_eig_real(M)
```

Comment: Checkout the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html), `linalg.eig` returns two values, which one do you need?

Answer (score 0):

As @aaossa says, `linalg.eig` (see the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html)) returns a tuple of two values, one containing the eigenvalues, the other the normalised eigenvectors

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg

def get_eig_real(matrix):
    eigenvalues, eigenvectors = linalg.eig(matrix)
    return eigenvalues.real

test_matrix = np.diag((1, 2, 3))

real_eigenvalues = get_eig_real(test_matrix)
print(real_eigenvalues)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) the function `linalg.eig` returns tuple of

> The eigenvalues, each repeated according to its multiplicity.

And

> The normalized (unit “length”) eigenvectors ...

Depending on your needs you can use either of those functions:

```
# to retrieve real parts of eigenvalues
def get_eig_real(matrix):
    eig, _ = linalg.eig(matrix)
    return eig.real

# to retrive real part of normilized eigenvectors
def get_eig_norm_real(matrix):
    _, norm_eigvectors = linalg.eig(matrix)
    return norm_eigvectors.real
```